# Remove columns from SQL output where all values are 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

SO,
I'm not that great with PIVOT's in SQL (as I usually do this in Excel with "flat" data), but managed to cobble together the following output:

```
CONTID  FULLNAME    %!  %%  %3
001     Store 1      0   0   0
002     Store 2      0   0   0
003     Store 3      0   0   0
004     Store 4      0   0   0
005     Store 5      0   0   0
```

(hope that displays properly)

Here is my SQL:

```
USE mydb 

go 

WITH basequery 
     AS (SELECT c.contid, 
                p.fullname, 
                h.keyalm 
         FROM   customer c 
                LEFT JOIN clogs h 
                       ON c.serialno = h.serialno 
                LEFT JOIN contact P 
                       ON c.serialno = P.serialno 
         WHERE  evtype = 1 
                AND p.conttype = 1) 
SELECT * 
FROM   basequery 
       PIVOT(Count(keyalm) 
            FOR keyalm IN ("%!", 
                           "%%", 
                           "%3", 
                           "%4", 
                           "%6", 
                           "%8", 
                           "%9", 
                           "%A", 
                           "%B", 
                           "%C", 
                           "%D", 
                           "%E", 
                           "%F", 
                           "%G", 
                           "%H", 
                           "%I", 
                           "%K", 
                           "%L", 
                           "%M", 
                           "%O", 
                           "%P", 
                           "%Q", 
                           "%R", 
                           "%S", 
                           "%T", 
                           "%U", 
                           "%V", 
                           "%W", 
                           "%X")) AS pvt --I truncated some of this
```

What I'd like to is somehow not display the columns that have all 0's for their totals, like the ones displayed here. Attempted to do a "WHERE" after the pivot, but I got yelled at for that.

I've truncated the columns for SO purposes, but my output actually has like 100 columns, and majority are all 0's. Would like to eliminate those from the displayed pivot if possible. Is there a right way to do this?

Comment: I think you need dynamic sql to achieve what you want: you have to use it in order to determine which of there values `'%!'`, `'%%'`, `'%3'`, etc, are going to appear inside the `FOR` clause of the `PIVOT`.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos I'm not sure that is that easy since you still need to scan all rows *after* the pivot to determine if there are only 0 for any column.

Comment: @bartover The dynamic query is used to determine which values are going to take part in the `FOR` clause in the first place. You don't have to perform any filtering afterwards, since all-zero values are simply not going to be there.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos help me out here - how do you know (before doing the actual pivot) that values in a given column will be all zero so the dynamic sql can omit them from the FOR clause?

Comment: @bartover have a look at this piece of dynamic sql used to built the string containing the values to be used in the `IN` http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6bed04/2

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos ah, you're right! I failed to see that for a column to be omitted a given value cannot appear *anywhere* in the original dataset regardless of grouping columns, hence a `DISTINCT` is enough. Neat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query for dynamic columns:

```
USE mydb 

go 
declare @str as nvarchar(max),@query as nvarchar(max);
set @str = stuff((SELECT distinct ',['+keyalm+']' FROM   customer c 
                LEFT JOIN clogs h 
                       ON c.serialno = h.serialno 
                LEFT JOIN contact P 
                       ON c.serialno = P.serialno 
         WHERE  evtype = 1 
                AND p.conttype = 1 for xml path('')),1,1,'')
set @query = 
'WITH basequery 
     AS (SELECT c.contid, 
                p.fullname, 
                h.keyalm 
         FROM   customer c 
                LEFT JOIN clogs h 
                       ON c.serialno = h.serialno 
                LEFT JOIN contact P 
                       ON c.serialno = P.serialno 
         WHERE  evtype = 1 
                AND p.conttype = 1) 
SELECT * 
FROM   basequery 
       PIVOT(Count(keyalm) 
            FOR keyalm IN ('+ @str +')) AS pvt'
execute sp_executesql @query
```

Comment: WOW Mohammed! I have 0 understanding of what's happening with that query (I'll spend some time learning it), but it appears to work beautifully!

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, you are counting on keyalm, and you want to eliminate all rows where spreading column consists of 0s. That means that for particular combinations of contid and fullname(grouping columns are identified by elimination ) there are no rows in clogs. If so, you can eliminate such rows in cte. Add new column in cte

`Count(keyalm) Over(Partition by contid, fullname) as cnt`

and filter cte before pivoting `where ctn > 0`.

So you end up with something like this:

```
DECLARE @clogs TABLE
    (
      serialno INT ,
      keyalm NVARCHAR(MAX)
    )
DECLARE @contact TABLE
    (
      serialno INT ,
      fullname NVARCHAR(MAX)
    )
DECLARE @customer TABLE
    (
      contid INT ,
      serialno INT
    )


INSERT  INTO @customer
VALUES  ( 1, 10 ),
        ( 2, 20 ),
        ( 3, 30 )

INSERT  INTO @contact
VALUES  ( 10, 'Michael Jordan' ),
        ( 20, 'Dennis Rodman' ),
        ( 30, 'Scottie Pippen' )


INSERT  INTO @clogs
VALUES  ( 10, '%!' ),
        ( 10, '%%' ),
        ( 10, '%3' ),
        ( 20, '%%' );
WITH    basequery
          AS ( SELECT   c.contid ,
                        p.fullname ,
                        h.keyalm ,
                        COUNT(h.keyalm) OVER ( PARTITION BY c.contid,
                                               p.fullname ) AS cnt
               FROM     @customer c
                        LEFT JOIN @clogs h ON c.serialno = h.serialno
                        LEFT JOIN @contact P ON c.serialno = P.serialno 
                       --WHERE  evtype = 1 AND p.conttype = 1
             ),
        wrapper
          AS ( SELECT   contid ,
                        fullname ,
                        keyalm
               FROM     basequery
               WHERE    cnt > 0
             )
    SELECT  *
    FROM    wrapper PIVOT( COUNT(keyalm) FOR keyalm IN ( "%!", "%%", "%3" ) ) AS pvt
```

Output:

```
contid  fullname        %!  %%  %3
1       Michael Jordan  1   1   1
2       Dennis Rodman   0   1   0
```